# Telugu (unicode) font rendering in emacs

Tags: fonts, emacs, unicode

I sometimes edit text in telugu language. However, when I open the file (UTF-8 encoded) in GNU emacs (version 23.1.50.1 on Ubuntu Jaunty) the text rendering is incorrect. The same text file opened in gedit is rendered correctly.

Here's a snippet: ప్రకృతికి ఉదయం అంటే ఇష్టమేమో rendred in gedit:

[image: telugu text rendering in gedit]

And, the emacs rendering of the same text:

[image: telugu text rendering in emacs]

Wherever glyphs need to be composited (not sure if it's the right word), emacs (or whatever library it uses) is not doing it right.

Is there anyway to fix this? Perhaps tuning some setting in my configuration? Any ideas, please?

Comment: Superuser stuff

Comment: @aviraldg: 
Are you suggesting this isn't the place to ask this question?

Comment: @prakash Yeah. http://superuser.com/

Comment: Looks like I don't have enough reputation to migrate this question over to superuser. And, I don't have any reputation on superuser to post images or (more than one) hyperlinks :( I'll have to re-post the question without images and *one* backlink to this.

Comment: @Prakash: this will be migrated automatically; you don't have to do anything but wait.  please don't crosspost.

Comment: Oops. Already reposted. Let me try to delete.

Comment: I am disappointed to see this issue as still unresolved. I am seeing the same problem with Gujarati too: https://lists.gnu.org/r/help-gnu-emacs/2018-08/msg00033.html

Answer (score 1):

gedit uses Pango, which gives it access to advanced text layout functionality for Indic languages. There is no version of emacs that supports Pango, so there is no way to fix this.

Comment: (Please read [NL] below as line breaks, as new-lines are being collapsed here.)

The emacs I am using does seem to be linked to libpango:
>> ldd /usr/bin/emacs23-x | grep pango | sort [NL]
 libpango-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpango-1.0.so.0 (0xb7a33000) [NL]
 libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 (0xb7b5f000) [NL]
 libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 (0xb7bab000) [NL]
FWIW, examining /usr/bin/gedit shows the same info. I am sure I am missing something, but does this mean emacs is linking in pango, but not using it, or is not using it as it was intended to be?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue in Gujarati. I was debugging this for a while, and was finally able to fix it by ensuring that I installed both **m17n-lib** and **m17n-db**.

Here's my installation script:

- The script installs **m17n** (lib and db) version **1.8.0** at `$m17n_install_dir`.
- So `$m17n_install_dir` should be the only thing you need to modify in that script.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# http://www.nongnu.org/m17n/
# http://download.savannah.nongnu.org/releases/m17n/

# http://download.savannah.nongnu.org/releases/m17n/m17n-lib-1.8.0.tar.gz
# http://download.savannah.nongnu.org/releases/m17n/m17n-db-1.8.0.tar.gz
#
# Tue Aug 14 12:49:04 EDT 2018 - kmodi
# The m17n-db is *needed* for composites (like the "સ્તે" in
# Gujarati "નમસ્તે") to work correctly.
# Ref: https://lists.gnu.org/r/help-gnu-emacs/2018-08/msg00033.html

m17n_version="1.8.0"
m17n_install_dir="${STOW_PKGS_ROOT}/m17n/${m17n_version}"

./configure --prefix="${m17n_install_dir}"
make

mkdir -p "${m17n_install_dir}"
make install
echo ""

## * m17n-db *
m17n_db="m17n-db-${m17n_version}"
m17n_db_tar_gz="${m17n_db}.tar.gz"
echo "Downloading ${m17n_db_tar_gz} .."
if [[ -f "${m17n_db_tar_gz}" ]]
then
    rm -f "${m17n_db_tar_gz}"
fi
if [[ -d "${m17n_db}" ]]
then
    rm -rf "${m17n_db}"
fi

wget "http://download.savannah.nongnu.org/releases/m17n/${m17n_db_tar_gz}"
tar xf "${m17n_db_tar_gz}"

echo ""
echo "Installing ${m17n_db} .."
cd "${m17n_db}" || exit

# See the README about charmaps and glibc
#
# Tue Aug 14 12:17:13 EDT 2018 - kmodi
# Below code is adapted from the "./get-glibc.sh" script to use the
# glibc mirror on Github. The official URL for glibc download was
# timing out today. So using the mirror on Github.

# Original values:
# GLIBC_VERSION=2.3.2
# GLIBC_DOWNLOAD_URL=https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc
# charmap_dir="glibc-${GLIBC_VERSION}/localedata/charmaps"

GLIBC_VERSION=2.28
GLIBC_DOWNLOAD_URL=https://github.com/bminor/glibc/archive
charmap_dir="glibc-glibc-${GLIBC_VERSION}/localedata/charmaps" # Yes, it is "glibc-glibc-.."

echo "Downloading ${GLIBC_DOWNLOAD_URL}/glibc-${GLIBC_VERSION}.tar.gz .."
if wget "${GLIBC_DOWNLOAD_URL}/glibc-${GLIBC_VERSION}.tar.gz"
then
    echo "Extracting the \"charmaps\" directory .."
    if tar xfz "glibc-${GLIBC_VERSION}.tar.gz" "${charmap_dir}"
    then
        :
    else
        echo "!! Can't find the \"charmaps\" directory in the tar ball."
        exit 1
    fi
else
    echo "!! Downloading failed"
    exit 1
fi

./configure --prefix="${m17n_install_dir}" \
            --with-charmaps="${charmap_dir}"
make
make install
```